# Application crashes after upgrading device to iOS12

Tags: ios, crash-reports, ios12

My enterprise application is working fine till iOS 11. Yesterday once I updated one of the device to iOS 12 and tested the application. It is crashing at launch.
While debugging I found it works fine on Simulator but crashing on device even before main is called.

## Crash Log

```
    Incident Identifier: 34B04574-6BD3-4A5F-A352-244841532EAE
    CrashReporter Key:   8a642341ed3bb03fe6ac849ed5857efe31b26830
    Hardware Model:      iPod7,1
    Process:             MyApp [1822]
    Path:                        /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7E7F1946-60D5-4354-B1B6-C981FEE8F82B/MyApp.app/MyApp
    Identifier:          #########
    Version:             18.8 (18.8)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Role:                Foreground
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]
    Coalition:           #########


    Date/Time:           2018-09-25 12:33:25.6270 -0400
    Launch Time:         2018-09-25 12:33:25.5276 -0400
    OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.0 (16A366)
    Baseband Version:    n/a
    Report Version:      104

    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x822bc15100000002
    VM Region Info: 0x822bc15100000002 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 9379803191291412483  
          REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
          MALLOC_NANO            0000000280000000-00000002a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
    --->  
          UNUSED SPACE AT END

    Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
    Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
    Terminating Process: exc handler [1822]
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000019118dff8 _platform_strcmp + 8
    1   MyApp                   0x0000000100b0f4d0 0x1005e0000 +                 5436624
    2   MyApp                   0x0000000100b0f5d8 0x1005e0000 + 5436888
    3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001907530b0 call_load_methods + 184
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190754610 load_images + 180
    5   dyld                            0x00000001012b2388 dyld::notifySingle+ 9096 (dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList*) + 440
    6   dyld                            0x00000001012c4750 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization+ 83792 (ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 440
    7   dyld                            0x00000001012c3798 ImageLoader::processInitializers+ 79768 (ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 136
    8   dyld                            0x00000001012c3854 ImageLoader::runInitializers+ 79956 (ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 84
    9   dyld                            0x00000001012b26a4 dyld::initializeMainExecutable+ 9892 () + 220
    10  dyld                            0x00000001012b7468 dyld::_main+ 29800 (macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 4600
    11  dyld                            0x00000001012b1044 _dyld_start + 68
```

Already went through Apple developer forum and other stack overflow crashes. But so far no pointers. Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Comment: no clue. It might be a plist related item. And did you try with another device as well?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried on 2 devices myself so I don't think it is device specific. Working on your plist pointer to check if something is wrong with that. Just to be sure you are talking about info.plist and not settings bundle, Correct? BTW, what is in the log suggest that issue may be due to plist?

Comment: nothing in the log suggests that. I'm just spitballing that it's a different iOS version and depending on what you're doing sometimes you need _more/new_ permissions/entitlements

Comment: currently experiencing the same issue, so if you get anywhere, please can you update here as well?

Comment: Same issue occurs for me too but the application is not the enterprise one. Just public one. Looking for a solution.

Comment: worth sharing any Cocoapods we are all using to see if there is anything in there?

Comment: So far found nothing. Have a created issue on apple developer as well. I'll share if I get any directions. @John I am not using any external pods only 1 internal pod to integrate sled which is running fine with other applications we have.

Comment: @AshwiniM ok, thanks for the update

Comment: @AshwiniM quick update.  Managed to track down our issue.  We are using an old version of Crittercism.  Have removed that and it's no longer crashing.

Comment: @AshwiniM Can you share the link to Apple forum in order to see discussion there. Maybe someone from apple team responded to it?

Comment: @Honey Have you had a chance to find any information about that? Maybe we can compare our pods? For me the issue happens of "ne.filter" thread. I was trying to look for it in the project but failed. Maybe someone has an idea about it?

Comment: @Yuriy I never ran into this issue. I don't know

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My app crashing with old version of Crittercism iOS SDK.

Comment: I switched from an old Crittercism manual installation to the latest CocoaPods version per https://docs.apteligent.com/ios/ios_install.html. That resolved my crash on launch.

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching and testing finally found the solution for weird crashing in iOS 12!!!
The answer above me is right and the problem indeed is to remove any old code of "Crittercism iOS SDK"

But ... this alone didn't solved my problem. there are other lines which should be erased if you are using this library through "PODS".

Please search for this line : "-ObjC -l"Crittercism_v5_4_0"" or any other combination (maybe for other library number)  and remove all.
Build and enjoy :)